# C++ reading csv into vector, getline() problem

Tags: c++, csv, vector, getline, long-long

My csv file data is look like this:

```
Palmer Shannon,1.66805E+12,7500,3020
Jonas Kelley,1.62912E+12,9068,1496
Jacob Doyle,1.61608E+12,1112,3502
Iola Hayden,1.60603E+12,6826,4194
```

This is my header file :

```
#ifndef client_h
#define client_h
#include <string>

const int MAX_CLIENT = 20;

struct client {
    std::string name;
    long long  accountNum;
    int pwd;
    double balance;
};
```

For the first data, the String name is refer to *Palmer Shannon*, long long is refer to *1.66805E+12*, int pwd is perfer to *7500* and double balance is refer to *3020*.

This is my main.cpp file and i try to create a vector to hold the csv file data.

```
string str;
    std::vector<client> readClientProfile;
    while (getline(data, str))
        {

        client Client;
        istringstream iss(str);
        string token;
        getline(iss, Client.name, ',');

        getline(iss, token, ',');
        Client.accountNum = std::stoi(token);


        getline(iss, token, ',');
        Client.pwd = std::stoi(token);

        getline(iss, token, ',');
        Client.balance = std::stoi(token);


        readClientProfile.push_back(Client);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < readClientProfile.size() - 1; i++)
    {

            std::cout << readClientProfile[i].name << "  "<<endl;
            std::cout << readClientProfile[i].accountNum << "  "<<endl;
            std::cout << readClientProfile[i].pwd << "  "<<endl;
            std::cout << readClientProfile[i].balance << "  "<<endl;

        }
```

The question is when i run the program, the accountNum is just show the first world **1**.  I can not change the type of the accountNum because this is the assignment request.How to read the long long type with the variable,character and symbol?

Answer (score 2):

The account number in your file is stored as `1.66805E+12`.  This is a floating point number, not an integer.  When you use `stoi` to convert it to an it parses the string and stops at the `.` since that isn't a valid symbol in an integer.  That means `stoi` is going to return `1` for all of the account numbers.  You can fix this by first converting `1.66805E+12` to a `double` using `stod`, and then you can store that `double` as an integer like

```
getline(iss, token, ',');
Client.accountNum = std::stod(token);
```